# CMAKE Как подключить динамическую библиотеку генерируемую подпроектом

Tags: c++, cmake

Структура проеткта следующая:

```
RootFolder
--Bin
--Build
--Dependencies
---Soul-Byte-Engine-Core //Он как раз и должен генерировать dll-библиотеку
-----Bin
-----Build
-----Dependencies
-------SFML
-----Include
-------WindowManager.hpp
-----Sources
-------WindowManager.cpp
-----CMakeLists.txt
--Sources
---Application.cpp
--CMakeLists.txt
```

Код из RootFolder/Dependencies/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core/Include/WindowManager.hpp

```
#pragma once

namespace SoulByteEngineCore
{
    class WindowManager
    {
    private:
        unsigned int windowWidth{};
        unsigned int windowHeight{};
        bool UseFullScreen = false;
        const char* windowTitle{"SoulByte Engine Window"};
    private:
        bool isCanBeCreated = true;
    private:
        void _CreateWindow();
        void Update();
        void Destroy();
    public:
        WindowManager(unsigned int windowWidth = 800, unsigned int windowHeight = 600, const char* windowTitle = "");
        ~WindowManager();
    public:
        void ChangeResoulution();
        void SetFullScreen();
        void SetWindowed();
    };
}
```

Код из RootFolder/Dependencies/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core/Sources/WindowManager.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


#include<WindowManager.hpp>

namespace SoulByteEngineCore
{
    SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager::WindowManager(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const char* title)
    {
        this->windowWidth = windowWidth;
        this->windowHeight = windowHeight;
        this->windowTitle = windowTitle;

        SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager :: _CreateWindow();
    }


    void SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager::_CreateWindow()
    {
        sf::RenderWindow CurrentWindow(sf :: VideoMode(this->windowWidth, this->windowHeight), this->windowTitle);
        
    }
}
```

Код из RootFolder/Sources/Application.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <WindowManager.hpp>

int main()
{
    SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager();
}
```

Код из RootFolder/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(TestByteSoulEngineWindow VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX C)

file(GLOB TARGET_SOURCES
    "Sources/*.cpp"
    "Sources/*.cxx"
    "Sources/*.cc"
    "Sources/*.c"
)

add_subdirectory(Dependencies/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core)

include_directories(Dependencies/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core/Include)

add_executable(Application ${TARGET_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(Application PUBLIC WindowManager)

set_target_properties( Application
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../Bin"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../Bin"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../Bin"
)
```

Код из RootFolder/Dependencies/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(soul-byte-engine-core VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX C)


set(DEPS_SFML_DIRECTORY_PATH "Dependencies/SFML")
set(DEPS_SFML_HEADERS_PATH "Dependencies/SFML/include")


set(PLATFORM_HEADERS_PATH "Include")

set(WINDOW_MANAGER_HEADER_PATH "Include/WindowManager.hpp")
set(WINDOW_MANAGER_SOURCE_PATH "Sources/WindowManager.cpp")


##set ( CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON )

include_directories(${PLATFORM_HEADERS_PATH})


option(BUILD_SFML_FROM_SOURCES "Use this if you want to build Byte Soul Engine from source code with SFML(WindowManager dependency). Compiling SFML from sources guarantees that the resulting library is perfectly tailored for your CPU/OS" ON)

option(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER "Component of Byte Soul Engine that provides feautures for window control" ON )
option(USE_BUILD_MANAGER_AS_STATIC_LIB "Build WINDOW_MANAGER as static library [.lib - Windows and .a for UNIX/Unix-Like] By default it's OFF and is built as dynamic library [.dll - Windows and .so - Unix/Unix-Like] " OFF)

function(BUILD_SFML)
    add_subdirectory(${DEPS_SFML_DIRECTORY_PATH})
    include_directories(${DEPS_SFML_HEADERS_PATH})
endfunction()

function(CHECK_SFML_INSTALLED)
    if(SFML_FOUND)
        if(BUILD_SFML_FROM_SOURCES)
            message("SFML WAS DETECTED ON THIS SYSTEM, BUT WILL BE BUILT FROM SOURCE CODE!")
            BUILD_SFML()
        else()
            message("SFML SUCCESSFULLY DETECTED ON THIS SYSTEM AND WILL BE USED!")
        endif()
    else()
        message("COULD NOT FIND SFML INSTALLED ON THIS SYSTEM! BUILDING SFML FROM SOURCES...........")
        BUILD_SFML()
    endif()
endfunction()


function(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_AS_STATIC)
    add_library(WindowManager STATIC ${WINDOW_MANAGER_SOURCE_PATH} ${WINDOW_MANAGER_HEADER_PATH})
endfunction()

function(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_AS_SHARED)
    add_library(WindowManager SHARED ${WINDOW_MANAGER_SOURCE_PATH} ${WINDOW_MANAGER_HEADER_PATH})
endfunction()

if(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER)
    include_directories(${WINDOW_MANAGER_HEADER_PATH})
    CHECK_SFML_INSTALLED()
    if(USE_BUILD_MANAGER_AS_STATIC_LIB)
        BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_AS_STATIC()
    else()
        BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_AS_SHARED()
    endif()
    target_link_libraries(WindowManager sfml-graphics sfml-audio sfml-window)
    install(TARGETS WindowManager DESTINATION lib)
    install(FILES ${WINDOW_MANAGER_HEADER_PATH} DESTINATION include)
    
set_target_properties( WindowManager
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../Bin"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../Bin"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../Bin"
)

install(TARGETS WindowManager DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${WINDOW_MANAGER_HEADER} DESTINATION include)

endif()
```

При попытке обратиться к :

```
SoulByteEngine-Core :: WindowManager();
```

я получаю от компоновщика: unresolved symbol, однако без этого обращения ни на каком из этапов сборки проблем не возникает.

Comment: P.S я бы очень хотел реализовать возможность выбора типа библиотеки: статическая или динамическая. Вы можете это увидеть если взглянете на код из: RootFolder/Dependencies/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core/CMakeLists.txt